# --excludepath/--relocate certain paths by default when installing with rpm/yum/dnf

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I want to free-up space occupied by `.mo` files in `/usr/share/locale` and for that reason I replaced that directory with a symlink to `/tmp/.locale-blackhole` and configured auto-creation of this dir with

`/etc/tmpfiles.d/locale-blackhole.conf`:

```
# Conserve disk space for unused locales

# pre-create the dir below and clean 1-day-old files periodically:
d /tmp/.locale-blackhole 0755 root root 1d

# pre-create symlinks
L+ /tmp/.locale-blackhole/locale.alias - - - - ../../usr/share/locale.persist/locale.alias
L+ /tmp/.locale-blackhole/en - - - - ../../usr/share/locale.persist/en
L+ /tmp/.locale-blackhole/en_US - - - - ../../usr/share/locale.persist/en_US
L+ /tmp/.locale-blackhole/fr - - - - ../../usr/share/locale.persist/fr

# do not cleanup the paths below:
x /tmp/.locale-blackhole/locale.alias
x /tmp/.locale-blackhole/en
x /tmp/.locale-blackhole/en_US
x /tmp/.locale-blackhole/fr
x /tmp/.locale-blackhole/keepme
```

It works except when `glibc-common` is updated or reinstalled, the symlink `/tmp/.locale-blackhole/locale.alias` is replaced with a regular file.

So I want to configure `rpm` to always relocate this file to `/usr/share/locale.persist/`. Is this possible?

Or even better, is it possible to just exclude some languages under `/usr/share/locale/` from rpm extraction?

Comment: Are you really tight enough on disk space that the ~200MB in `/usr/share/locale` makes a difference? Can you restrict %_install_langs based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/959380/how-do-i-install-generate-all-locales-on-fedora) posting?

Comment: @doneal24 adding `%_install_langs C:en:en_US:en_US.UTF-8` to the .macros file helped. Thanks!